# Make InvisibleComma's in output

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, display

Entering something that outputs like $a_{bc}$ is as simple as <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, using `\[InvisibleComma]`s.

The form of the expression is actually `Subscript[a,b,c]`, which outputs like $a_{b,c}$ when evaluated normally.  I want to write code to output `Subscript[a,b,c]` with invisible commas, instead of doing something like converting the variables to strings and concatenating (e.g. `/.Subscript[f_,b__]:>Subscript[f,StringJoin[ToString/@{b}]]`).  Presumably the 'right' way to do this is with box stuff?

I may have seen enough with boxes lately that if you guys point me in a direction you know is fruitful and not ultimately nasty, I could come up with it.

This comes up when writing code to pretty print derivatives, e.g.

```
//.{f_[x__]:>f,Derivative[x_,y_][f_]:>Subscript@@Join[{f},ConstantArray[x,nx],ConstantArray[y,ny]]}
```

Comment: `r1 = Subscript[a_, b_, c_] -> Subscript[a, bc]` and `Subscript[a, b, c] /. r1` ?

Comment: `rule = Subscript[x_, y__] :> Subscript[x, Row[{y}]];`